# Error: bcap library not found

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, compiling

During compiling of reaver-wps in Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine on windows 7 32-bit host I received the error `error : bcap library not found`.  I already installed sqlite3 , libsqlite3-dev , libcap-dev, cannot install libcap0.8-dev it says not found.

when I Googled it i found other programs which depend on libcap also has this issue so i think the problem is with libcap

The error I get:

```
root@maged-VirtualBox:~/reaver-1.4/src# ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
error: pcap library not found!
```

Answer (score 1):

To easily find the corresponding development package for Ubuntu when configure fails with such error, you can use http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpcap

Usually the package that you're looking for contains the following description:

```
 "development library for <lib name>"
```

Then open a terminal to install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a spelling mistake. I couldn't install `libcap0.8-dev` because it is `libpcap0.8-dev` not `libcap0.8-dev`

For anybody with the same problem, installing these packages should work:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libcap-dev libpcap-dev
```